# How to store extreme large numbers in Node.js without losing any precision?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, largenumber

I need to be able to add, subtract, and store (via JSON) numbers up to `+/-99.99*10^2040` with full precision (down to 0, so not 0.9 or lower).  The main two issues I've had are that Infinity is far below that and that big numbers lose precision.  I would highly prefer not just converting the whole thing into a string since the JSON file would quickly become messy.  I thought of doing something like `["99", "50"]` to symbolize `99*10^50` but that either loses precision or takes up more space than just using a string.  I've also looked into biginteger libraries but similar problems arise, especially with storing the numbers in JSON.

Comment: Is Node.JS your only option? Perhaps there is a better tool for the job.

Comment: So you want to use JS, but you want numbers with more precision that the number type offers, but you *don't* want to use one of the existing JS libraries that does larger numbers? (Or are the numbers you need beyond even what those libraries can do?)

Comment: Node.js is my only option E.Sundin unless I want to redo a large amount of code from scratch and potentially work in a language I'm less familiar in.  Also nnnnnn I've been unable to find a library with JSON support.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't have a native object for handling big integers like Java does. You need to implement the logic yourself, which I see you're already off to a great start on.

Alternatively, you can use this popular implementation. [Here's a library for BigInteger native in JavaScript.](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js)

You can install this to your node.js project via npm:

`npm install big-integer`

Then, you can include it where you need it:

`let bigInt = require("big-integer");`

After which, usage is quite straight forward:

`let largeNumber = bigInt("75643564363473453456342378564387956906736546456235345");`

If you need floating point numbers, [Here's another node library for handling BigDecimal.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bigdecimal)

Note that JSON doesn't accept either of these object types. If you absolutely must store via JSON, then you should store the mantissa and exponent separately, and accept that you're going to lose precision in many cases.

Comment: You would likely store these numbers on JSON as a string, not as a numeric type.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post I've tried biginteger libraries and none of them have had JSON support.  Also @jfriend00 I don't require any decimals, just extremely large full precision whole numbers.  So BigInteger would work assuming that I was able to store it via JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The [big-numbers](http://bignumbers.tech) library support json. Installation:

```
npm install --save big-numbers
```

Usage:

```
var numbers = new BigNumbers();
var bigNumber = numbers.of('75643564363473453456342378564387956906736546456235345');
console.log('Json:' + JSON.stringify(bigNumber));
```